# Error after changing let to const and changing i++ with i+1 in a for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tslint

I was coding after disabling tslint for a while and when I enabled it later on, I saw some errors and fixed it.

From this:

```
for (let index = 0; index < combinedUniqueIndexes.length; index++)
```

To this:

```
for (const index = 0; index < combinedUniqueIndexes.length; index + 1)
```

But after doing so my code simply crashes! I have no clue what I am doing wrong!
Please help this poor soul!

(If anybody needs the whole project then i can give that too, just ask!)

Comment: You can't change value of `const`  you need to use let or var for counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors in the second for loop.

1. Change `const index = 0` to `let index = 0`. `const` means that the identifier can’t be reassigned and `let` means the identifier can be reassigned.
2. Change `index + 1` into what you had before `index++`. `index++` actually means `index = index + 1` making `index` increment by 1 each time you go through the for loop.

The reason it was crashing was because every time the for loop went to change `index` it couldn't because `const` wouldn't allow it to change.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change a `const` value so incrementing it *should* fail. You should use `let` instead of `const` for your iterator. See the MDN docs for [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

Answer (score 1):

```
 index + 1
```

does not change `index`, your loop is infinite. To increase, do

```
 index += 1
```

Comment: Short syntax : index++

Answer (score 1):

You can’t use a constant for a `for` loop index. The loop works by incrementing the index variable every iteration, but you can’t do that with a constant. You need to use `let` here.

Additionally, you changed the 3rd part of the loop to not actually mutate the index, so now your loop runs forever it never increments the index.

You need to go back to what you originally had. What is your reason for changing this?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using a classic C-style `for` loop, the index cannot be a constant, because it gets incremented (or decremented) on every iteration.

```
for (let i=0; i < length; i++) { ... }
```

I don't recommend using `var` to declare and initialize the index, because it will exist beyond the scope of the loop. Generally, `let` is safer, `var` can create difficult to detect bugs.

However, when you are using a `for of` or `for in` loop, it might good idea to use a constant:

```
for (const item of arr) { ... }
```

or...

```
for (const key in obj) { ... }
```

You can get away with that, because in `for of` and `for in` loops, the index gets initialized at the beginning of every iteration. Just remember not to use `for in` to iterate through strings and arrays (ordered data structures) because it might mess up the order of elements (never happened to me, but there is no guarantee  that it won't).

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong with you for loop

```
for (const index = 0; index < combinedUniqueIndexes.length; index + 1)
```

1. You can't change value of a `const`. Do not use const for counters.
2. `index+1` you're not assigning back the value of expression back to index. so index will always be same.

So you should you use code something like this

```
for (let index = 0; index < combinedUniqueIndexes.length; index++)
```

Or

```
for (let index = 0; index < combinedUniqueIndexes.length; index += 1)
```

Or

```
for (let index = 0; index < combinedUniqueIndexes.length; index = index + 1)
```